# GUI file managers infinitely loading folders never showing content [desktop: KDE5 - tested file managers: Dolphin, Thunar, Nautilus]

Tags: linux, gui, desktop, file-manager, freedesktop

GUI file managers do not show any folder content anymore.

Running KDE5 [plasma-desktop-5.7.5-1.fc23.x86_64] on Fedora 23 [4.7.4-100.fc23.x86_64] GUI file managers suddenly stopped to show contents of local directories. For example, Dolphin is showing forever the 'loading folder' bar for $HOME, root or any other local directory.
The behaviour is the same for other file managers as Nautilus or Thunar.
Rebooting/testing older kernels did not change the behaviour.

However, directories and files are viewable/accessible (r/w) in terminals.

Also I have not noticed any problems with GUI programs running within KDE5.
So, I assume that actual file access is not hindered.

Interestingly, contents of FUSE mounted file systems (as EncFS or sshfs) are shown, when entering their complete path in the file manager's address bar.

So far I have not been able to identify the problem, maybe suspecting a problem with some freedesktop API??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not identifying the actual problem, I solved the problem by creating a fresh take of the KDE config directory

```
mv $HOME/.kde/share/config $HOME/.kde/share/config.backup
```